# Get upperbound and lower bound using a mid range

Tags: java

I am trying to find he upper and lower bound of the data below

```
0,0
4,0
12,1
16,1
16,2
18,4
24,5
26,8
28,9
```

If my mid-range is 5 . I need to group my data as

1 st column = [0,4,12,16,16],[18,24,26,28] (rest of the values can be just added to list even if it is not of size 5)

But instead of storing every elements into an array. I would like to store only [0,16],[18,28].

Like wise for 2 nd column [0,2],[4,9].
But using my current code I am only getting [0,16].

Below is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Trail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputvalues = new ArrayList<String>();
        inputvalues.add("0:0.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:4.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:12.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:16.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:16.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:18.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:24.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:26.0");
        inputvalues.add("0:28.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:0.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:0.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:1.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:1.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:2.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:4.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:5.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:8.0");
        inputvalues.add("1:9.0");
        /*
         * Iterate through data
         */
        int counter = 0 ;
        double prevV = 0;
        String currKey = "";
        String prevKey = "";
        ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>();//REsult with upperbound and lower bount
        int splitRange = 5;
        for(String lst : inputvalues){
            counter++;
            System.out.println("\n*********lst********** "+lst);
            String[] parts = lst.split(":");//key
            currKey = parts[0];//value
            double v = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
            if(prevKey.equals ("")){
                /*
                 * prev value empty.
                 * Initial value
                 */
                arr.add(v);
                System.out.println("Initial range "+arr);
            }
            else if(prevKey.equals(currKey)){
                /*
                 * Both incoming values are same
                 */
                System.out.println("----------same key-----------");
                if(counter == splitRange){
                    arr.add(v);
                    System.out.println("RESULT-------->"+arr);
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else{
                    prevV = v;
//                  System.out.println("Previous v "+prevV);

                }
                /*
                 * initial counter
                 */
                if(counter == 1 ){
                    arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    arr.add(v);
//                  System.out.println("counter equals 1 "+arr);
                }
            }
            else if (!prevKey.equals(currKey)){

                if(counter != splitRange){
//                  System.out.println("In not equalls");
                    arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    arr.add(prevV);
//                  System.out.println("arrr "+arr);
                }

                counter = 0;

                if(counter == 1 ){
                    arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    arr.add(prevV);
//                  System.out.println("counter equals 1 "+arr);
                }

                counter++;
                /*
                 * previous value
                 */
//              System.out.println("Previous v "+prevV);
                arr.add(prevV);
//              System.out.println("prev not equal to current "+arr);
            }

            prevKey = currKey;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to figure out the same.

Comment: for a start try `if(prevKey.equals ("")){`

Comment: and why are you creating new `arr = new ArrayList<>();`  ?

Comment: for each mid range I need to get different arraylist  eg : for colid: 1 [0,16][18,28] and for colid: 2 [0,2][4,9]